# ROS2 C++ Message Builder Pattern: error use of auto before deduction of auto

Tags: c++, ros, ros2

On Ubuntu 20.04, ROS2 Foxy, GCC version 9.4.0, C++ rclcpp node.

The completely undocumented builder pattern for messages works as follows. (Odometry for example)

```cpp
#include <nav_msgs/msg/odometry.hpp>
// https://docs.ros2.org/foxy/api/nav_msgs/msg/Odometry.html
nav_msgs::msg::Odometry const odom = nav_msgs::build<nav_msgs::msg::Odometry>()
  .header(std_msgs::msg::Header()) .child_frame_id("")
  .pose(geometry_msgs::msg::PoseWithCovariance())
  .twist(geometry_msgs::msg::TwistWithCovariance());
// This works // Excuse typos
```

This is opposed to the "classic" style (since ROS committee won't allow initialization with arguments):

```cpp
nav_msgs::msg::Odometry odom; // Notice can't make it const
odom.header = std_msgs::msg::Header();
odom.header.stamp = builtin_interfaces::msg::Time(); // or = node.get_clock()->now();
odom.header.frame_id = "...";
// ... etc, fill in other odometry members
```

Problem: But a lot of the time I get a cryptic error, and I can't discern why.
Ex, if I tried:

```cpp
odom.header = std_msgs::build<std_msgs::msg::Header>() // Error here, on ')'
  .stamp(node.get_clock()->now()).frame_id("map");
```

**error:** use of `auto std_msgs::build() [with MessageType = std_msgs::msg::Header_<std::allocator<void> >]` before deduction of `auto`

I tried to make the type as explicit as possible; casting to target type, creating an intermediary variable of the target type, no change in error.
To even understand that the builder pattern exists, unless you found some cryptic scrawl on the internet (like so), you have to dig into the generated header files, so I did.
You will find

```cpp
/// vim /opt/ros/foxy/include/std_msgs/msg/header.hpp
// generated from rosidl_generator_cpp/resource/idl.hpp.em
// generated code does not contain a copyright notice

#ifndef STD_MSGS__MSG__HEADER_HPP_
#define STD_MSGS__MSG__HEADER_HPP_

#include "std_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/detail/header__builder.hpp"
#include "std_msgs/msg/detail/header__traits.hpp"

#endif  // STD_MSGS__MSG__HEADER_HPP_

/// vim /opt/ros/foxy/include/std_msgs/msg/detail/header__builder.hpp
// ...
namespace std_msgs {
namespace msg {
namespace builder {
// ... bunch of builder classes calling the next, ex:
class Init_Header_stamp { ... };
} // namespace builder
} // namespace msg

template<typename MessageType>
auto build();

template<>
inline
auto build<::std_msgs::msg::Header>()
{
  return std_msgs::msg::builder::Init_Header_stamp();
}

}  // namespace std_msgs
```

Using this as a guide, I wondered if I repeated / copy-pasted the template declaration in my code, and replaced `auto` with the actual type(s), would that work... but at this point my c++ fu was exhausted, and all the cobbled substitutions just gave more weird errors.
Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
The parent type includes the child type definitions, but not the builder definitions.
In this example, to include Odometry and then use the builder pattern on Header, you also need to `#include <std_msgs/msg/header.hpp>`.

Why: (no, really, why was it implemented like this, where is the documentation)

```cpp
/// In vim /opt/ros/foxy/include/nav_msgs/msg/detail/odometry__struct.hpp
// Include directives for member types
// Member 'header'
#include "std_msgs/msg/detail/header__struct.hpp"
// Member 'pose'
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/detail/pose_with_covariance__struct.hpp"
// Member 'twist'
#include "geometry_msgs/msg/detail/twist_with_covariance__struct.hpp"
/// Notice, doesn't include the full child header, which also includes __builder.hpp,
/// but just the sub-header with type definitions, __struct.hpp!
```

So include every header manually if you use it's builder pattern.

Comment: In case you think [etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) might be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was only unofficially familiar, tho by that I think I did it right? I don't ask questions too often, but this one was driving me up the wall for several days, and I had the question written out & lingering, just in case I could find an answer before others (or the void of silence) wasted their time. But when found, I noticed that the submit a question page changed, and there's no longer the "answer your own question" box. Nonetheless, I felt compelled to drop it anyway, because if you don't know the truth, it just looks like a good ol' really weird C++ problem instead...

Comment: No worries, I am just passing on some knowledge that some people sent to me as well :)